# Send form data from Tornado HTTPClient

Tags: python, tornado

How can I use the [`fetch` method](https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/httpclient.html#tornado.httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient.fetch) to send multipart form data in a `POST` request? I don't see this mentioned in the documentation anywhere.

I tried this, but the arguments on the server ([`HTTPServerRequest.arguments`](https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/httputil.html?highlight=body_arguments#tornado.httputil.HTTPServerRequest.arguments)) were empty:

```py
client.fetch(
    '/foo/bar',
    headers={'Content-Type': 'form-data'},
    body=urllib.parse.urlencode({'a': 1, 'b': 2})
)
```

Comment: This question is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/49791118/2954547

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a read here: [on another StackOverflow question answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49791118/tornado-testing-multipart-request-using-asynchttptestcase)

I believe any answer will more or less be similar to the link I've pointed out. The Http method you use should not matter at this point. Most of the issue is about constructing the multipart request.

Comment: It appears that my question is a duplicate, thank you.